# Could there be malware in Python/Javascript files that I purchased?

Tags: security

I recently purchased a django-react code off fiverr. I don't know too much about web development.
This may be just paranoia but is it possible that there could be some malicious malware in these kind of [Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb4J5.png). And that if I run the server then something could happen to the pc I run it on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, is it possible for HTML, PY, JS etc. files to contain malicious content, yes. If you run this server on a PC can any malicious content do bad things to the PC that it is being run on, yes.

Ok, so that is the scary side of this done. Let's consider the question a little more objectively. Let's think about how these files can contain malicious content, and more importantly what can you do about it.

1. **The author deliberately wrote malicious code into the files**

Of course this is possible, but in my opinion unlikely. People producing malware are looking for a return on the investment of their time. Writing a solution to your request on fiverr and including malicious content is a huge investment for minimal return.

Also, please bare in mind that any contractor / freelancer is building their career on trust. If they get caught writing malicious code for customers then their reputation will be impacted. There is a great book on [Who Can You Trust?](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Who-Can-You-Trust-Technology/dp/1541773675) which goes into the details about trust on platforms sharing goods and services.

If you do want to check for issues in the code, then I would use a static code analyser (e.g. Fortify) and a penetration test.

2. **The author has included an open source module that has malicious content**

This in my opinion is more likely. There have been examples in the past of modules published via sharing mechanisms e.g. NPM have contained malicious content. Here are a couple of examples:

- [Malicious NPM package](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2020/01/15/malicious-npm-package-taken-down-after-microsoft-warning/)
- [Bitcoin Stealer](https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/hk-en/security/news/cybercrime-and-digital-threats/hacker-infects-node-js-package-to-steal-from-bitcoin-wallets)

The good news here is that it is quite easy for you to check for known issues. For example, as you have JS files I assume there is a dependancy on npm, you can use [npm-audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit) to check the dependancies for security advisories.

In summary, in your position I would start by ensuring that the dependencies used by the code don't have any significant security advisories. Then, if the system is critical enough I would use a static code analysis tool (e.g. Fortify) to check the custom code. Finally, always good for a public facing system is getting a good penetration test done.

The key point here, is to think about the risk profile for the system and then decide what investment you need / should do to ensure the security of the system. Is this a customer facing system taking sensitive information (e.g. bank / credit card details), or, an internal intranet system? The first will require more stringent security checks to ensure that you keep your customers safe.